# TortoiseSVN is not showing commited file-size

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

After updating from TortoiseSVN 1.7 to 1.8.XX after commit no information about the commited file-size is shown. I think this information would be very useful!

But I cannot find the option, where I could activate this old feature.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Here is a screenshot showing my problem:
http://www.myimg.de/?img=tortoissvnnotshowingstabc08e.png

Comment: Try asking on the [TortoiseSVN mailing list](http://tortoisesvn.net/community.html).

Comment: Why do you think it would be very useful? You already know how large your file is by looking at your local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, that information was misleading and often inaccurate, for multiple reasons:

1. Data is compressed over the wire
2. Only diffs are transmitted
3. The SVN client libraries [don't provide this information in enough detail](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=901), so it was a bit of a guess on TSVN's part.